# change image in button while is pressed

Tags: java, android, xml

i have this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/fundo" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/fundo2" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

in other file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
         />

</FrameLayout>
```

and in the class

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mp.pause();
            return true;

        }

        return true;

    }
```

i don't know why, when the button is pressed the image don't change, what is the reason?

thanks!!

Comment: What method are you overriding in the class? Can you post the entire method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of android:background="@drawable/btn" please use android:src="@drawable/btn".

It Works for me .

Comment: thanks for reply. i think that the problem is when i use  <Button must be <ImageButton. But i get a crash in the app if i do this change.

Comment: you mush change button to imagebutton in your java file

Comment: yes, it's the problem. Anyway i change to an <ImageButton> and android:src="@drawable/btn" but i have the same problem. The btn when pressed don't change the image. In the simulator the middle button change but is not i expected

Comment: please use onClick() and see what happend .

Comment: yes, with onlick works, i must change the code, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Inside ur xml, for the button background give ur selector xml file name.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/ur state change xml file name"
/>
```

Comment: i don't understand. When you put ur, what mean? btn is my xml file name

Comment: keep ur 1st xml which u have given in this question as the background

Comment: sorry but i can' understand. I have a main.xml (the second block of code). The first block have the name of btn.xml, and exists in the paste res/drawable/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setBackgroundResource(ResId) for the change on button u can write this in the OnClick() method of the Button.